# Linking Isolated AD Domain Forests

Tags: active-directory, domain, windows-server-2016

My company manages a number of on-premises Windows Server environments for our customers. For the purpose of this question, these environments consist of a primary domain controller, secondary domain controller, and a WSUS. Each of these environments were created in isolation by other IT service providers, as such are in their own domain forests. See illustration below:

[image]
However, this isolated architecture that we have inherited creates a substantial overhead for helpdesk and on-site staff. We are contracted to provide on-site services, manage the customer’s updates (via WSUS), maintain the customer’s active directory policies (in order to reflect industry best practice), and carry out basic active directory administration. 
What am I trying to achieve? In a word ‘cascade’, I want to define one set of active directory policies and then have them cascade down to the customer’s domains, I want help desk staff and technicians to be able to sign-on using a common active-directory account, I want to push updates from a common WSUS account. 
To achieve the above, I could migrate them onto a common domain forest:

[image]

However, I want to maintain as looser coupling as possible. On a twelve monthly period, the customer could elect to migrate IT service providers - I would look to extricate them with minimal effort. Inversely, I want to be able to onboard new customers as quickly as possible with minimal impact to their environment. Therefore, I believe an approach based on forest trust relationships would be the best way forward:

[image]

What thoughts to people have on the above-proposed architecture? Are forest trust relationships the best way to achieve my aims?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This isolated architecture that we have inherited creates a
>   substantial overhead for helpdesk and on-site staff

First and foremost, your clients should be isolated from each other, and from you. The incurred overhead is your cost of doing business. That's what it means to be an MSP.

This as presented is a bad idea. You should not attemp to create Forest/Domain trusts between these clients and you, or between clients. Furthermore, none of these clients should be linked to each other at a network level. If my MSP attempted to do this I would fire them immediately.

This is what RMM's are for. There are a bazillion RMM solutions on the market, such as Kaseya VSA, SolarWinds RMM, Atera, Continuum, Pulseway, Itarian, ConnectWise, etc., etc. You should find one that fits your needs and your budget and use it.

Comment: thank you for your response and your engagement. You have raised some very interesting points that I hadn't considered. I should highlight this was very much a theoretical question. I will review the RMMs you have mentioned.

Comment: Glad to help...